# Echo value when select an option - PHP Only

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am just starting to learn php and I have some problem with my little project.
I create a DB that contain "members" table with "member_id" and "member_name" calumn.
I create a select box that is populated with members name. When I select a name and I click to submit button, I want to echo the member_id. How can I do that without javascript/ajax.

PS. I want to stay on the current page after submiting.

Thank you very much.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Select</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="post" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">

          <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td><select name="numeselect">
              <?php
                $numeselect=$_POST ["numeselect"];
                $host="localhost";
                $user="***";
                $password="***";
                $db_name="***";

                $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
                if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
                    echo "Eroare la coenxiune:" . mysqli_error();   
                }

                $selectare_nume = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nume_membru, id_membru FROM membri");

                while($nume_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'">'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></td>';
                while($id_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                echo '<td>'.$id_selectat['$id_membru'].'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';

                ?>
              <input type="submit" value="show id">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get form submit values like this

```
if(isset($_POST['numeselect'])){
    echo $_POST['numeselect'];
}
```

Change  options to this

```
echo '<option value="'.$nume_selectat['id_membru'].'">'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'</option>';
```

So the full script

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Select</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="post" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">

          <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td><select name="numeselect">
              <?php
                $numeselect=$_POST ["numeselect"];
                $host="localhost";
                $user="***";
                $password="***";
                $db_name="***";

                $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
                if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
                    echo "Eroare la coenxiune:" . mysqli_error();   
                }

                $selectare_nume = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nume_membru, id_membru FROM membri");

                while($nume_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$nume_selectat['id_membru'].'">'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></td>';
                while($id_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                echo '<td>'.$id_selectat['$id_membru'].'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';

                ?>
              <input type="submit" value="show id">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['numeselect'])){
    echo "<p>You selected member id: {$_POST['numeselect']}</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: Super, thank you very much, now it works. I have a little more question. Can you tell me a good php tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Select</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="post" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">

          <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php
                if(isset($_POST)) {
                  $numeselect = $_POST["numeselect"];
                  echo $numeselect;
                }
               ?>
              <select name="numeselect">
              <?php
                $host="localhost";
                $user="***";
                $password="***";
                $db_name="***";

                $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
                if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
                    echo "Eroare la coenxiune:" . mysqli_error();   
                }

                $selectare_nume = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nume_membru, id_membru FROM membri");

                while($nume_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'">'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></td>';
                while($id_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                echo '<td>'.$id_selectat['$id_membru'].'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr></table>';

                ?>
              <input type="submit" value="show id">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**What did I add?**

```
                if(isset($_POST)) {
                  $numeselect = $_POST["numeselect"];
                  echo $numeselect;
                }
```

Comment: it didn't work. Now I have this error: Notice: Undefined index: numeselect in C:\xampp\htdocs\form2.php on line 21.  However, if i click on submit, it echoes the name, not the id.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that without javascript/ajax.
>
> PS. I want to stay on the current page after submiting.

If by stay on the current page you mean NO page refresh, and you don't want to use javascript, it's not possible.

If you just mean you want to POST to the same page, then you would `echo` the variable in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: i expres myself wrong. it's not a problem if the page will be refreshed. important to me is to stay on current page. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use switch case, and 2 functions, first for the form, second for show value with code of Joni Salmi, example:

```
<?php

// action
$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == "undefined" || $action == "") $action = "form_member";

switch($action){
  // Member form
  case 'form_member': 
        form_member();
        break;

  // Show Member id
  case 'show_member':
     show_member();
     break;

}

function form_member(){
?>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Select</h2>    
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td>
    <form method="post" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="show_member" />
      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td><select name="numeselect">
          <?php
            $numeselect=$_POST ["numeselect"];
            $host="localhost";
            $user="***";
            $password="***";
            $db_name="***";


            $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
            if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
                echo "Eroare la coenxiune:" . mysqli_error();   
            }

            $selectare_nume = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nume_membru, id_membru FROM membri");

            while($nume_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
                echo '<option value="'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'">'.$nume_selectat['nume_membru'].'</option>';
            }
                            echo '</select></td>';
            while($id_selectat = mysqli_fetch_array($selectare_nume)){
            echo '<td>'.$id_selectat['$id_membru'].'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr></table>';

            ?>
          <input type="submit" value="show id">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



<?php
}


function show_member(){

  if(isset($_POST['numeselect'])){
    echo $_POST['numeselect'];
  }

}

?>
```